# Granting Access to view system queries in History GUI

Tags: user-interface, permissions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a backup role `BACKUP_ROLE` set up to allow a contractor to view our systems overnight and diagnose any problems that arise. I do not want to give it `SYSADMIN` or `ACCOUNTADMIN` privileges, but I would like `BACKUP_ROLE` to have access to view system queries in the history tab of the GUI.

I need them to click the "`Include Queries executed by user tasks`" and show these system queries listed below.

What permissions do I need to add to `BACKUP_ROLE` to make this work?

[image]

Comment: Any user will have the access to the Query History on GUI. For eg: a user with just Public role has the access to Query History. Is this not the case for your specific scenario? As in the user which is assigned BACKUP_ROLE is not able to view the Query History tab?

Comment: The user BACKUP_ROLE can see the query history tab. The issue is they cannot see System generated queries based off of scheduled tasks. if you look above in the picture, the user for all those queries is SYSTEM. the BACKUP_ROLE cannot see those queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grant "Monitor" privilege on the Warehouse to the role as follows:

```
grant MONITOR  on warehouse <WH name> to role BACKUP_ROLE;
```

Comment: OMG thank you! I'm a little embarrassed that was all it took but i appreciate your help!~